# SAXParseException when using spring-data-jpa tag

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sax

I'm trying to get Spring data JPA to work. I'm using the version **1.8.2.RELEASE**.

```
<!-- Spring Data JPA -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm also added Spring dependencies using version **4.1.9.RELEASE** :

- spring-core
- spring-beans
- spring-context
- spring-context-support
- spring-tx
- spring-jdbc
- spring-orm

Finally, I added Hibernate dependencies using version **5.0.5.Final** :

- hibernate-core
- hibernate-jpamodelgen
- hibernate-entitymanager
- hibernate-ehcache

also, I added hibernate-validator with version **5.2.2.Final**

Then, I created an applicationContext xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean name="logDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/myJndi"/>
</bean>

<bean id="logSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="logDataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.mycompany.persistance.entity.LogsData</value>
            <value>com.mycompany.persistance.entity.LogsOperation</value>
            <value>com.mycompany.persistance.entity.LogsConfiguration</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="configurationClass">org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="logTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="logSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.persistance.repository"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="logTransactionManager"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.persistance.repository"/>
```

The compiler tells me everything is ok.
However, when I try to launch my project, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd; lineNumber: 43; columnNumber: 63; src-resolve : Cannot resolve the name 'repository:auditing-attributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4158)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDAttributeGroupTraverser.java:80)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.traverseAttrsAndAttrGrps(XSDAbstractTraverser.java:643)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:1122)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:335)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseLocal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:164)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(XSDElementTraverser.java:392)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDElementTraverser.java:242)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1429)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:626)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:613)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2446)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1766)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:760)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:357)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
... 71 more
```

I can't find out why it is giving me this error.
I tried downgrading Hibernate version, Spring version, but I still get this error.

I can't downgrade spring-data-jpa to 1.2 (it seems the element "repository:auditing-attributes" appeared in 1.3) because of Spring dependencies (I have to use Spring 4).

Have you ever experienced the same type of error?
Do you know how to solve it?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, my application was expecting the spring-repository-1.8 xsd file to be added in the context. So I added these dependencies

```
xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.8.xsd"
```

It now works well.